# Get result set of 10 years before and 10 years after current year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**What I want:** I would like a result set that shows me the 10 years prior to and the 10 years after the current year.

**Example:** Being that this year is 2014:

```
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
```

**What I've tried:** I'm not a huge SQL guy so bear with me here:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(DATEADD(year, -10, GETDATE())) AS prevYear,
YEAR(DATEADD(year, 10, GETDATE())) AS nextYear,
YEAR(GETDATE()) AS currentYear
WHERE currentYear BETWEEN prevYear AND nextYear
```

Can someone help me out? Am I even close??

Comment: Why are you doing this in SQL?

Comment: @dvnrrs Does it matter why I am doing this in SQL? Bottom line is, I am doing this in SQL (if possible).

Comment: It matters because it sounds like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, and I was hoping to be able to suggest a simpler alternative.

Comment: I'm populating an HTML select element with these years and I wanted to avoid doing this in JS/jQuery and I don't want to download another 3rd party plugin. @Aaron's answer below is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (21) YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, number-10, GETDATE())) 
FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number;
```

Chances are you want to do something else with this data. One example might be to aggregate the data from some table, and include years in this range that aren't found in the table. Here's how you might do that:

```
;WITH y(d) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (21) DATEADD(YEAR, number-10, DATEADD(YEAR, YEAR(GETDATE())-1900,0))
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number
)
SELECT y.d, COUNT(o.key)
  FROM y 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.other_table AS o
  ON o.datetime_column >= d.d
  AND o.datetime_column < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, d.d)
GROUP BY y.d
ORDER BY y.d;
```

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, As per Microsoft Guidelines, more than five tables are not allowed to join in SQL Server. Is it correct? If not correct, as per your perspective how many tables are allowed to join in SQL Server for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to get these records from an existing table:

```
declare @thisYear int =  year(getdate())

select yourYear
from table1
where yourYear between @thisYear -10 and @thisYear + 10 
      and yourYear <> @thisYear --Assuming you don't need the current year
```

[**SQL fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b3c1/1)

Comment: Then @Aaron has given the solution.